# Windows installation check list

Tags: windows, installation

What is the general check list for every Windows client (Professional, Business, etc.) and Windows Server installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I do a lot of cloning in my work, I have created a checklist that I can give ya.  Its more of the same that Tim suggested, but also includes some specifics that are nice to have on a client's computer:

**Basics**

- Windows (with latest SP and updates)
- Antivirus
- MS Office (latest available)
- Firefox
- Chrome (optional)
- IE (latest)
- PDF Reader

  - Foxit (my personal preference)
  - Adobe Reader (not recommended by some Antivirus companies)
- Adobe Flash (This needs to be installed once in each browser)
- Java (latest)
- .Net (latest)

**Drivers**

- Audio
- Video
- Misc.

**Misc Software**

- Direct X (latest for your operating system)
- CutePDF (print directly to pdf instead of printer)

**Organization Specific Software**

- <Your own list here>

**Optional**

- Latest Window Media Player
- Quicktime

Answer (score 3):

In what environment? Production server? Home use? The "checklist" for a given setup will vary pretty widely depending on what you want to do.

In general, though, you should:

- Secure the installation as soon as you can

  - Get all security patches
  - Install reasonable antivirus/firewall software
- Get drivers installed for the hardware in the system
- Get network access working, if applicable
- Focus on other specific needs for the system (for servers, network services and (optionally) routing; for home use, whatever the user requires it to do)

  - Most systems: Java, Flash (with appropriate security restrictions)
  - For home use: Firefox/Opera/Chrome, MS Office/OpenOffice
  - For servers / production systems: routing (if it's a router), SSH/VPN/HTTP/FTP servers

Comment: I suspect he is dealing with a corporate environment (Professional or Business edition Windows client).